# load many makers google map

Tags: android, performance, google-maps

hey I customize google map makers as an image in my android app , it's working fine but currently it takes time to load markers since there are many markers around 200. Actually, i get the images from backend (parse.com) and then crop it to fit marker shape.

Is there any way to load markers faster?

```html
 View marker2 = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.marker, null);
 ImageView numTxt = (ImageView) marker2.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);

Bitmap bitmap1 = getBitmap(url1, MapActivity.this);
numTxt.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

markerOpts = markerOpts.title("Company").snippet("branch").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(MapActivity.this, marker2)));



public static Bitmap getBitmap(String url2, Context context) {
  FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(context);
  MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
  File f = fileCache.getFile(url2);
  //from SD cache
  //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
  Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
  if (b != null)
   return b;
  // Download image file from web
  try {
   Bitmap bitmap = null;
   URL imageUrl = new URL(url2);
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
   conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
   conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
   conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
   InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
   // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
   // if file not exist then it will create file
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
   // See Utils class CopyStream method
   // It will each pixel from input stream and
   // write pixels to output stream (file)
   Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
   os.close();
   conn.disconnect();
   //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
   // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
   b = decodeFile(f);
   return bitmap;

  } catch (Throwable ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
    memoryCache.clear();
   return null;
  }
 }


public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
  DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
  view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
  view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
  view.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  view.draw(canvas);

  return bitmap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You know for sure that you will need the pictures, so do that in an un-obtrusive way. Load them in the background **once**, while initializing. After you have loaded them once, just use them from your local environment. So, improvements:

- request the pictures and parse them in a background thread while initializing the software to not bother the user with it
- store the pictures when you have successfully extracted them and reuse them locally instead of rerequesting them

Comment: Thanks. Would you tell me how to request pic in background thread? do you mean AsynTask ?!

Comment: @Mariam, yes, you can do it with AsynTask. The main idea is to do it with a separate thread, so when the user looks at the content, the pictures are already extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image downloading library [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
It will handle image downloading and caching, memory usage, and you can crop an image to whatever size you need. And if you load the same image many times (what you probably do) Picasso will use cached image instead of downloading it every time, so that will speed up all the images downloading process.

To use this library you need to declare it in dependency tree of `build.gradle` file from `app` folder of your project in Android Studio, so it will look like this:

```
dependencies {

//some other dependencies
//...
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'//add this line
}
```

Then use it in code:

```
Picasso.with(MapActivity.this).load(url1).into(numTxt);
```

Comment: Thanks. anyway if you checked my code , in getBitmap method i use caching.